# Open an HDF5 file error

Tags: c++, hdf5

I created an HDF5 file open function like the following:

```
int OpenHDF5(string sFileName)
{   
    // Check for valid HDF5 file 
    if (!H5File::isHdf5(sFileName.c_str())) 
    {   
       // Invalid HDF5 file
       return -1
    }

    // Try block to detect exceptions raised by any of the calls inside it
    try
    {  
       // Turn off the auto-printing when failure occurs so that we can handle the errors appropriately
       Exception::dontPrint();

       // Now Open the file
       H5File file( sFileName.c_str(), H5F_ACC_RDONLY ); 
    }  

    // Catch failure caused by the H5File operations
    catch( FileIException error )
    {   
        error.printError();
        return -1
    }

    return 0
}
```

No compiling error occurred, but failed to link with the following exceptions:
Linking...
Creating library F:\Tips\Debug\Tips.lib and object F:\Tips\Debug\Tips.exp
TwinSatObservation.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::FileCreatPropList const H5::FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT" (?DEFAULT@FileCreatPropList@H5@@2V12@B)
TwinSatObservation.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class H5::FileAccPropList const H5::FileAccPropList::DEFAULT" (?DEFAULT@FileAccPropList@H5@@2V12@B)
F:\Tips\Debug\Tips.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

I added the following libraries to "Addtional Dependencies" input box of the VS 2008 Linker
    hdf5dll.lib 
    hdf5_hldll.lib 
    hdf5_cppdll.lib 
    hdf5_hl_cppdll.lib

Would you please tell me which library I forgot to add? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

As for hdf5-1.8.17 with either VS2010 or VS2015, defining `H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB` as a preprocessor setting (*Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions*) cures exactly the same symptom for me. Thanks to the [original post](https://lists.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_lists.hdfgroup.org/2016-March/009294.html).

Answer (score 2):

Add `HDF5CPP_USEDLL;_HDF5USEDLL_;` in *Preprocessor Definitions* input box.

Comment: Where is Preprocessor Definitions input box? is in in Linker->input? I'm using VS 2015 and can't find this!